# From factory the J-Bolt Gate hinge is too large, the gate will sag -how do I fix it?

Tags: hinges

I have the below two pieces. When #1 is connected to #2 which is set in horizontal position, #1's hole is too large and it goes downward, the result is that the gate will sag
[image: enter image description]
[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just hung the gate on one set of these it would be a problem. Also if you just used one bolt to hold the strap to the gate it would be a problem.

With that said if you build your gate as a rectangular element with proper cross brace so that the gate itself keeps its shape and then mount the straps to the gate with two bolts each you will not see gate sag due to the larger size hole in the strap versus the size of the post on the L-bolt.

Comment: It turned out that you can actually correct the position of the gate by adjusting the distance between the post and the pin, If the bottom pin is farther than the top one then the gate tilts toward the post with the hinges and compensates the lag due to above described issue.You just need to play from the two nuts that will sit on each side of the supporting post

Comment: @MiniMe - Yup, nice and adjustable too.

Answer (score 6):

You should have 2 or even 3 of these hinges to install on the gate which can be adjusted to correct the slope of a loose fitting pin. However if the pin is way too small I would check to see if the right hinge pin piece was supplied. Remember the top hinge pin is usually installed facing downward so the gate can not be lifted off reducing tour security. All others face up.

Comment: this is a great great point, I am just wondering why I could not remember that, I came across this a while ago